# counting points in grid cells in python, np.histogramdd

Tags: python, numpy, count, datagrid, grid

I have a numpy array including the coordinates of the points in 3-dimensional space:

```
import numpy as np 
testdata=np.array([[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.6,0.6,0.6],[0.7,0.7,0.7],[1.5,0.5,0.5],[1.5,0.6,0.6],[0.5,1.5,0.5],[0.5,1.5,1.5]])
```

Each row for one particle including 3 coordinates (x y z).There are 8 points in this example. is there any python package for griding the 3D space, then counting the particles in each cell?
I tried np.histogramdd in this way

```
xcoord=testdata[:,0]
ycoord=testdata[:,1]
zcoord=testdata[:,2]
xedg=[0,1,2]
yedg=[0,1,2]
zedg=[0,1,2]
histo=np.histogramdd([xcoord,ycoord,zcoord],bins=(xedg,yedg,zedg),range=[[0,2],[0,2],[0,2]])
```

and it seems it is working but the indexing is strange. I mean the final array that np.histogramdd returns has no meaningful indexing regarding the original coordinates. is there any other way for griding the 3d space and count the number of points in each cell?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are needing but you can use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
coords = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
df_coords = pd.DataFrame(coords)
df_coords.count()
```

Comment: I want to be able to define the cell sizes and then having the number of points in each cell (box) in the grid

Comment: can you make a small table of examples. I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: I've edited the post. I have 3-D coordinates for 8 points and I want to divide the space into a grid of cells and count the number of particles in each cell